# terminator panes automatically connect to different servers

Tags: gnome-terminator

I figured out few weeks ago how to start terminator with a custom layout instead of creating it manually (by using `terminator -l`). Now I would like to start terminator and have every single pane of my custom layout automatically connect to a remote server (unfortunately I have to manage multiple servers).
Is there any way or any scripting support/language to do that?

Comment: Do you need scripting support for that? You could use multiple profiles with custom commands, and then assign each pane a profile.

Comment: I am not aware about 'terminator profile'. I read few posts mentioning option -p, but I haven't seen this option listed in the terminator man page I have. I am using version 0.95

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My terminator configuration looks like this:

```
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    # some settings
  [[root]]
    # some colour settings
    use_custom_command = True
    custom_command = sudo -i
    exit_action = restart
  [[lab]]
    # some more colour settings
    use_custom_command = True
    custom_command = ssh -R 2022:localhost:22 lab
    exit_action = restart
  [[server]]
    # some more colour settings
    use_custom_command = True
    custom_command = ssh server
    exit_action = restart
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      type = Window
      order = 0
      parent = ""
    [[[child1]]]
      labels = None, None, None, None
      type = Notebook
      order = 0
      parent = child0
    [[[terminal1]]]
      profile = root
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = child1
    [[[terminal2]]]
      profile = lab
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = child1
    [[[terminal3]]]
      profile = server
      type = Terminal
      order = 2
      parent = child1
    [[[terminal4]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 3
      parent = child1
```

By combining profiles with `custom_command`, I get four tabs on startup, one with a root shell, two opening ssh connections and a fourth running normal shell.

These options are documented in the [`terminator_config(5)` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/terminator_config.5.html)

Comment: It works!What do you use to avoid inserting the passwords every time? SSH Key file or any other tool/command?

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile ssh keys.